# Javascript onclick function trouble

Tags: javascript, onclick, click

I'm using a popover in bootstrap, and I want it to close when the user clicks anywhere else on the screen.  The code I have is this:

```
$('#popover').bind('click', function() {
    $(".popover").live('click', function(){ return false; });
    $(document).one("click", function() { 
        alert('click'); 
    });
});
```

The problem is that the click on the button is triggering the alert.  For some reason javascript uses that click to start the function and trigger the click event inside of it.  What am I doing wrong?

EDITED:

This code doesn't do anything:

```
$(".popover").live('clickoutside', function(){
        alert('click'); 
    });
```

Comment: It doesn't close automatically? Are there any errors in your javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

Check out these:

> - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation
> - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopImmediatePropagation

If your `.popover` is inside `#popover`, you're triggering events from all the affected elements.

---

**NOTE:** jQuery's `live` is in deprecating process, use the alternatives:

> - http://api.jquery.com/on/
> - http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: The .popover div isn't created until the #popover button is clicked.  I don't understand how to use the links you gave.

Comment: from your code, you are not "creating" the ".popover"! you are just "attaching an event" (a click event) on it when you click the "#popover" element.

Comment: No, the .popover element doesn't exist until the #popover is clicked.  That's how the bootstrap popover works.

Comment: A user opens the popover by clicking on the #popover button.  I want the popover to close when a user clicks outside of the popover.  THe popover is closed by doing $('#popover').popover('hide').